# Parse packet xmel in Ejabberd 13.12

Tags: xml, erlang, ejabberd

I am capturing packets using the filter_packet hook. Now how can I parse this xmlel and get the value of the desired tags ?

Comment: Can you show any examples of what you get and describe what dificulties do you have?

Comment: @Dimitry Belyaev `<<"<message xmlns=\"jabber:client\" to=\"test1@kushdev.ssqueal.org/20500423901404388005197218/Gajim\" type=\"chat\" id=\"66\"><body>as</body><x xmlns=\"jabber:x:event\"><composing /></x><thread>eJFMuziLDXZIdeWRvUCdjPfyIZJoucVE</thread></message>">>` 
How do I get the value of <body> tag for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost sure there must be already parsed `xmlel` object passed which is quite easy to deconstruct. Anyway, if the only thing you managed to get from ejabberd is just raw stanza you can use `xmerl` to do the job. It is documented and has [user's guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/xmerl/xmerl_ug.html)  to start with.

```
1> S = <<"<message ...">>.
2> (fun(Str) -> {Root, []} = xmerl_scan:string(Str), [{xmlText, _, _, _, Text, _}] = xmerl_xpath:string("//body/text()", Root), Text end)(binary_to_list(S)).
"as"
3>
```

Comment: new ejabberd and mongooseim use `exml` library, not xmerl

Comment: They never did. It doesn't mean this has to be done the same way.

Comment: The same way, you can use XPath.

Answer (score 2):

actually when you use hooks in the ejabberd or in the mongooseim, you'll get already parsed message. And you can retrieve 'body' subelement from that parsed structure  using xml or exml libraries. For instance:

```
 exml_query:subelement(YourMessage, <<"body">>),
```

or

```
 xml:get_subtag(Message, <<"body">>),
```

or you can iterate manually all subelements and do something with them

```
   #xmlel{name= <<"message">>, children= Els} = Message,
   [ do_something(Body) || #xmlel{name = <<"body">>} = Body <- Els ]
```

When you retrieve body element, you can extract its value

```
xml:get_tag_cdata(Body)
```

or

```
exml_query:cdata(Body)
```

As an option, if you are sure that message contains body, you can extract value of body at once

```
exml_query:path(Message, [{element, <<"body">>},cdata])
```